# Why is my template specialization check insufficient for handling the corresponding type correctly?

Tags: c++, templates, casting, template-specialization

Context: I have a property bag that has public methods to accept int, bool and string properties. And all of them call a template private function whose snippet is attached below.

Question: I am checking the template specialization to add the property to the appropriate map. But the compiler errors with code C2440 "cannot convert from string to int" and C2440 "cannot convert from string to bool". I'm not sure why that's the problem.

Attempts at resolving:
I tried to static cast but it seems like it has the error where it cannot cast because it cannot convert from string to int (or bool!).

```
template <typename T>
void PropertyBag::Add(const string& name, const T value)
{
    string errorMessage;
    if (!IsValidPropertyName(name, errorMessage))
    {
        m_pFailureHandler->Handle(errorMessage);
        return;
    }

    if (!IsPropertyNameUnique(name, m_content))
    {
        m_pFailureHandler->Handle("Property '" + name + "' is not unique");
        return;
    }

    if (is_same<T, int32_t>::value)
        m_content.intProperties[name] = value;
    else if (is_same<T, string>::value)
        m_content.stringProperties[name] = value;
    else if (is_same<T, bool>::value)
        m_content.boolProperties[name] = value;
    else
        m_pFailureHandler->Handle("Unsupported value type");
}
```

Comment: use "if constexpr" (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If) instead of the regular "if" for the type checks (i.e. is_same... etc.)

Comment: If you are stuck with pre-11 c++, you can use reinterpret_cast<>. This should be a safe cast, since you just checked for it.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you wait until the function body to do your test, the entire function body has to b able to compile, it does not prune the bodies of if statements that can't run.

Write a function that is nothing but the map add:

```
void add(std::string const & name, bool value)
{
m_content.boolProperties[name] = value;
}
// And one for others
void add(std::string const &, ...)
{
// failure
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are stuck with pre-11 c++, you can use reinterpret_cast<>. This should be a safe cast, since you just checked for it.

```
if (is_same<T, int32_t>::value)
    m_content.intProperties[name] = *reinterpret_cast<const int32_t*>(&value);
// etc...
```

But that's not the proper way to do it.  You should let the type system do the hard work instead. I you have access to the type of m_content. I suggest you create these 3 overloads:

```
struct Content
{
   void setproperty(const std::string& name, bool b)
   {
       boolProperties[name] = b;
   }

   void setproperty(const std::string& name, int32_t n)
   {
       intProperties[name] = n;
   }

   void setproperty(const std::string& name, const std::string& s)
   {
       stringProperties[name] = s;
   }
};
```

If you can't change Content, you can create free functions

```
   void setproperty(Content& content, const std::string& name, bool b)
   {
       content.boolProperties[name] = b;
   }

   void setproperty(Content& content, const std::string& name, int32_t n)
   {
       content.intProperties[name] = n;
   }

   void setproperty(Content& content, const std::string& name, const std::string& s)
   {
       content.stringProperties[name] = s;
   }
```

Your add function then becomes:

```
template <typename T>
void PropertyBag::Add(const string& name, const T value)
{
    string errorMessage;
    if (!IsValidPropertyName(name, errorMessage))
    {
        m_pFailureHandler->Handle(errorMessage);
        return;
    }

    if (!IsPropertyNameUnique(name, m_content))
    {
        m_pFailureHandler->Handle("Property '" + name + "' is not unique");
        return;
    }
    setProperty(m_content, name, value);        
    // or m_content.setProperty(name, value);
}
```

Comment: With `reintepret_cast`,  you would have to take the address of `value`